# Aliens invade Earth but have no end of problems controlling it

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

Years ago, I read a short story about aliens invading Earth, written from their perspective.  All I remember is that the aliens were more militarily evolved, having conquered many worlds, but were not as "evolved" as humans. The story had a humorous tone.

I think the author was Eric Frank Russell or Fredric Brown, but not sure.

Anyone has any ideas what this story title and who the author is?

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337). When did you read it?  What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: Could be by Christopher Anvil...he did a lot of that,

Comment: I suspect this is "The Aliens Who Knew, I Mean, Everything" by George Alec Effinger. Even if it isn't, it should be.

Comment: @JoeL. - You may be unaware, but we [don't close unaccepted story-ID questions as dupes](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/20774), even if you're very sure that it's a dupe.

Comment: Great answers...thank you....and yes, dupe question.  Sorry, I'm a noob here!

Comment: @Valorium: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something. [This question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123600/sf-short-story-alien-apes-invade-during-nuclear-war/123609#123609) *does* have an accepted answer.

Comment: @EdwardPatience is it indeed Christopher Anvil's Pandora's Planet? And asking a duplicate question is no problem at all, it's just that we make them point to the other one.

Comment: @JoeL. For a [story-identification] request to be closed, both the dupe and the dupee need to have (possibly informally) accepted answers.

Comment: @JoeL. - What he said.  ↑↑↑