# Sci-fi book about alien invaders

Tags: story-identification

The invaders were some sort of humanoid (I think) that easily takes over earth and spreads humans all over the galaxy (seem to have a big empire) only to find that the humans are actually much smarter than the invading aliens, and they start to exploit the other alien races as well as the invaders.

I read it in swedish when I was a kid and found it very funny, but cannot for the life of me remember either the title or the author.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You've provided some information about what you're looking for, but more would be helpful. Look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for suggestions on additional information you can add. If you think of anything please edit it into your question. Do you have any idea if the book was originally written in Swedish or translated from some other language? Do you recall how or why the invaders spread earthlings all over the galaxy? Do you think the book was intended to be humorous? any extra details will help...

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123600/sf-short-story-alien-apes-invade-during-nuclear-war

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a lot like the Christopher Anvil short story Pandora's Planet which was later expanded into the novel [Pandora's Legions](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/0671318616/0671318616.htm).

The basic concept you mention about humans outsmarting the invading aliens is expressed by the following summaries:

"The mighty Centran Empire had been conquering star systems for centuries -- and then they took on Earth. And in spite of their more advanced weapons, the Centrans weren't sure just who had conquered who."

"Pandora's Legions has a cleaver concept for its plot. A galactic empire has invaded Earth. The only problem for them is that other than having the ability for space travel, their technology is no more advanced than roughly 18th Century Earth; and that the Earth's inhabitants seem to be a lot smarter. The book tells the story of what happens when these seemingly hapless aliens get out classed by us lowly "Earthmen". "

Then the aliens get the idea of sending humans out to fight:

[Thrift Book review](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/pandoras-legions_christopher-anvil/395021/#isbn=0671318616)

A classic Christopher Anvil type story and quite fun to read.